# Terminate loop on first value produced by stream (Rx)

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, rx.net

I have the following Rx method chain and I am looking to clean/improve the `Select` method shown below, can this be done with an existing Rx operator, tried using `Amb` but queried all ISINs and return the first Price produced.

I want the first Price produced for an ISIN and not bother querying any other ISIN, in otherwords I want to call GetPrice in a serial manner - try first ISIN, try second ISIN, try third ISIN etc...

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        GetIsins()
            .Select(isins =>
            {
                *decimal? price = null;
                foreach (var isin in isins)
                {
                    price = GetPrice(isin)
                        .Take(1)
                        .Wait();
                    if (price.HasValue)
                        break;
                }
                return price;*
            })
            .Subscribe(price =>
            {
                if (price.HasValue)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Got a price...");

            });

    }

    public IObservable<string[]> GetIsins()
    {
        return Observable.Return(new []
        {
            "US9311421039",
            "TR9311421033",
            "UK3342130394"
        });
    }

    public IObservable<decimal?> GetPrice(string isin)
    {
        return Observable.Return((decimal?)100m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I have understood the question correctly, you probably need to make the `GetPrice` operation a side-effect of subscribing to the observable.

```
GetIsins()
    .SelectMany(isins => isins)
    .Select(isin => Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        return GetPrice(isin);
    }))
    .Concat() // or .Merge(1)
    .Subscribe(price =>
    {
        if (price.HasValue)
            Debug.WriteLine("Got a price...");
    });
```

The `Concat` operator ensures that each `IObservable<decimal?>` in the sequence will have to complete before subscribing to the next one.
The `Defer` operator ensures that each `IObservable<decimal?>` will not start before it is subscribed (ensures that it is a *cold* observable in other words).

Comment: thanks, the of Merge(1) for the actual code works

Comment: The `Concat` operator [behaves wierdly](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1634) in the current version of the Rx library (5.0.0). My advice is to use the `Merge(1)` operator instead, until the issue with the `Concat` is fixed.